# passing arguements to url in template in django 1.6?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to pass `argument` (an integer) to the `url` in `template`. but I get error when I tried the following:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div id="sidebar"><a href="{% url "blogapp.views.singlepost" %}?'post_id'={{post.id}}">{{ post.title }}</a></div>

I also tried:
<div id="sidebar"><a href="{% url "blogapp.views.singlepost" %}?post_id={{post.id}}">{{ post.title }}</a></div>
```

I tried both. but failed.
I followed these [articles](http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/articles/passing-variables-named-patterns-django). but it did not help.
Any suggestions. I am using `django 1.6`

EDIT:
`URLconf`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blogapp.views',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'djangoLesson.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^$', 'allposts',name='allposts'),
    url(r'^world/$', 'hello'),
    url(r'^all/$','allposts'),
    url(r'^all/get/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$','singlepost'),
    url(r'^language/(?P<language>[a-z\-]+)/$','language'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', 
        'view_post',
        name='blog_post_detail'),
)
```

Comment: what error are you getting? do you want the `'post_id'` to be in single quotes?

Comment: You should post the relevant url definition.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: please explain what is wrong, so that I could correct?

Comment: Actually my mistake, I misread the article, it's actually right. You don't seem to have followed it at all though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Also can you comment on your thoughts on this post: you have solved a similar problem for a question I linked there. so you can help me out here.plz...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543037/django-error-init-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-max-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="sidebar"><a href="{% url 'blogapp.views.singlepost' post_id=post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></div>
```

Since you are using template tags, you dont need `{{post.id}}` again inside of template tag.